# Centralized or Component-based Styling Structure?

Tags: vue.js, components, bem

I've two elements: "select-status" and "select-date", I use BEM notation and Vue.js.

Is it common to set the styling of this two elements in a centralized location using BEM notation or makes it more sense to create two components and to set the stylings for each component seperatly?

I mean, if I would create two components and set the stylings for each component seperatly then every equal style between those two similar elements would be created twice. According to this: Is it better to get rid off componentbased styling and wouldn't it be better to style elements in a centralized location?

Answer (score 0):

**Component-based styles** is the solution I will prefer. BEM allow, and even advise duplication between components. BEM assure you that when you modify one component you will not break another one. This isolation comes with a price: duplication and a less standardization. It also comes with some benefits, for example, less complexity. *So duplication, here, is often the simplest and right answer.*

If you really want to, you can avoid duplication. You will have to find a sub-block that will be common between this two components. For example, you can create a `select-input` block that will be generic. it will be able to handle the specificity of a date, a status, or anything else. This solution is great for the three following reasons:

- **it allows scaling**. For now, maybe you just have status and dates. But it's nice to be prepared for the future and you will easily handle more types.
- **it separates styles and functionalities**. In BEM, you should have names that defines what it looks like, not what it does. It's not a `contact-form-submit-button` (what it does) but a `button button--primary` (what it looks like). So if you have the exact same styles for another form, you can reuse it! So for example, instead of `select-date`, you will have `select-input select-input--small`.
- **it separates logic components and styles components**. Two Vue components could use the same block styles and perhaps compose with different elements. I still find this global styles as component-based styles, since every block is independent of each other.